# Tensor product of projective modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, projective-module

> How do we prove tensor product of two projective modules is projective?

My attempt: Let $P ,P'$ be projective modules. By equivalent conditions we have $K ,K'$ such that $K \oplus P$ and $K' \oplus P'$ are free. And hence by splitting $(K \otimes K') \oplus (P \otimes P')$, free implies projective ?

Is there any other way?

Comment: "Hence by splitting" needs more explanation. Your proof is only a sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following facts:

1. Tensor products of free modules are free.
2. The tensor product is a [functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor). Hence, if there are [split monomorphisms](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+monomorphism) $M \to M'$ and $N \to N'$, it induces a split monomorphism $M \otimes N \to M' \otimes N'$.
3. A module $P$ is projective iff there is a split monomorphism $P \to F$ into a free module $F$.

The claim follows. This is almost the same proof as yours, but it is a bit simpler since we don't need to distribute the summands and it uses more general easy facts and combines them - making the proof more conceptual.

There are also other proofs. For example this one:

1. A composition of [exact functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_functor?wprov=sfla1) is exact.
2. $P$ is projective iff $\hom(P,-)$ is exact.
3. We have an isomorphism of functors $\hom(M \otimes N,-) \cong \hom(M,-) \circ \hom(N,-)$.

The claim follows immediately.